# How to increase messages per second in paho using python

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I am using paho-mqtt by Eclipse.
I installed Paho on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and on my laptop running on Ubuntu 16.04. I connected my Raspberry Pi to my laptop using a LAN cable. I am using my laptop as a server, i.e. I'm using localhost as server.

I am publishing from Raspberry Pi, and I am able to publish only approximately 200 messages per second. On other hand, my laptop being subscriber I can only receive about 20-25 messages per second.
I have attached the code for the publisher and subscriber. How can I send more messages?

Publisher code:

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as mqtt
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)

a = time.time()
num = 0

while (time.time() - a) < 1.0:
    try:
        data = int(ser.readline())
        mqtt.single("test", data, hostname="10.42.0.1")
        num = num + 1
    except ValueError:
        None

print(num)
ser.close()
```

Subscriber code:

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as mqtt
import time

b=0
a = time.time()

while True:
    msg = mqtt.simple("0", hostname="10.42.0.1")
    b=b+1
    print(msg.payload, b)
```

Comment: Did you consider rewriting your code in some more efficient language? Python is interpreted. Most compilers produce faster code. Have you tried to code your software in C++, Rust, Go, Ocaml ...? They are likely to run faster.

Comment: On the RaspberryPi, `localhost`  is your RaspberryPi, not your laptop

Comment: Sorry to see your question has been down-voted. To my mind it is a perfectly reasonable, well-asked question and you have made a good attempt yourself. Don't be put off, Stack Overflow is a great resource and community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, serial IO is slow;

Secondly, if you read the doc or source of paho-mqtt, you'll find that mqtt.single() create a new TCP connection for each function call, it hurts the performance, I suggest you use mqtt.Client class to do the job;

Lastly, if the rate of Pub is really matter, there exists a C implementation of 
 [MQTT client](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c)

Comment: Initially I used 9600 baud rate, I then changed it to 2000000 and now it is working perfectly fine. I can publish 32000 messages in 10 sec.
And as you suggested, instead of single subscribe, I used client loop for both publish and subscribe. So I receive same number of messages that I publish.

Comment: @Bryan Can you also tell me that how can I use `max_inflight_messages_set()`

Comment: @Darshil inflight is designed to restrict the number of un-confirmed messages between Client and Server, it normally for messages with QoS_1 and QoS_2, because QoS_0 message don't need a confirmation from peer side. for example, if you set max inflight value to 1, and send two messages with QoS_1 the same time, paho.Client won't deliver the second message before it received the PUBACK of the first message